# USB Ethernet MAC Address conflict

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

I have two USB to Ethernet (cheap Chinese ones) and they both have same MAC address. I need to put them in the same Ubuntu Server (16.04) system as fail over connections, hence cheaping out.

Having two same Ethernet ports with same MAC address causes problems. Any way to change those via USB dev or something so that network-manager doesn't freak out?

Forgot to add: both are recognized, one as `enp0s25u10` (changes) and `rename7` (changes)

Regards

Comment: You can perform MAC Spoofing ([Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones)) but be care about collision.

Comment: but the name changes, so that would also fix the name to one thing?

Comment: You can try using [random MAC address](https://askubuntu.com/q/1076798/11392) via systemd.link file combined with udev rule

Comment: Change mac address using udev rules. Check this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1286678